# Interactively Display graphs in matplotlib in python

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, matplotlib

For the life of me, I can not get `matplotlib` to display graphs in `ipython` inactively.

I've tried two approaches - each time, I get the same results:

```
In [10]: plot([1,2,3])
Out[10]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x104e9ca50>]
```

Here are the two approaches I have tried so far:
Using [the documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/shell.html) as a guide, I tried two different approaches:

First:

```
ipython --pylab

plot([1,2,3])
xlabel('hi mom')

In [3]: plot([1,2,3])
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x107e369d0>]
```

Second:

```
ipython
import numpy
import pylab

In [5]: pylab.plot([1,2,3])
Out[5]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x104ca7b90>]
```

How do I get the plot to display?

Comment: not clear what you mean by inactively in your text and iteratively in your title.

Comment: Call `pylab.show()`, or if you want them to pop up automatically, call `pylab.ion()` before creating a figure.

Comment: @PhilCooper Updated the title.  My bad on the spelling.

Comment: @JoeKington Just tried both of those.  Nothing 'popped up'.  `In [6]: pylab.ion()

In [7]: pylab.plot([1,2,3])
Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x101d59b90>]

In [8]: pylab.show()`

Comment: @mikebmassey - Hmm... Are you running a remote session, by chance? If not, try @BrenBarn's suggestion.  If you are running things remotely (e.g. through `ssh`), be sure you've enabled X-forwarding.

Comment: @JoeKington Not remote.  Followed BrenBran's suggestion below.  That seems to be the correct path.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible you have a non-GUI backend set.  Try doing `pylab.get_backend()` to see what backend you have set.  Look at the documentation [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) and [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html) to see how to set your backend.

Comment: Just checked: 'MacOSX'.  I see how to change it via the documentation, but any suggestion on which one to use?  For now, I'm messing around with `matplotlib` and will want the graph to refresh on my screen when I plot something new.

Comment: MacOSX should be a GUI backend according to the docs, so I don't know why it's not working.  Assuming you're sure you've got it set to interactive mode (as suggested in comments above) you could try any of the other interactive backends listed on the doc page (e.g., TkAgg).  You may also want to ask on the matplotlib mailing list.